# Importing users into Zizaco/Confide

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a mysql database where I store the login credentials of our users. The database scheme is different from the database scheme which Confide is using. Some of the fields in my database are similar to the ones Confide is using such as username, email and password, but some fields which are required for Confide are currently not in my database such as remember_token.

I was wondering what would be the best approach to import my current users into the mysql database that confide is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create remember_token varchar(100) on users table than import your data.

Comment: Thanks! Should I generate a random value for remember_token or is there a specific rule I need to follow when creating a value for remember_token?

Comment: You just need to import the data, and laravel has a special function in the User.php module which will generate token for the new entries. and for importing you don't need to create random number for it, just import it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to import my users.